# how to convert a monthly period in a date?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mydate' : ['1985m3','1985m4','1985m5']})

df
Out[18]: 
   mydate
0  1985m3
1  1985m4
2  1985m5
```

How can I convert these monthly periods into a proper `datetime` (artificially using the first day of the month, such as `'1985-03-01'` for the first row)?

I can of course strip the month and do it *the hard way* but is there a better pandonic way?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't recognize you with the change in name (-:

Comment: hahaha well its the same name actually

Comment: I could swear I remember different accents.  Oh well.  So much for being funny.

Comment: yes, the pronounciation is the same. I used new crazy characters instead of the good old noobie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `pandas.to_datetime` with Python [time directives](http://strftime.org/) where '%Y' for year, 'm' hard code for the letter m, and '%m' for month:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.mydate, format='%Ym%m')
```

Output:

```
0   1985-03-01
1   1985-04-01
2   1985-05-01
Name: mydate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```